# how to sort from greatest to least in a .csv file in python

Tags: python

Hello I'm currently trying to go through and sort the data I have in a .csv for average snow fall for each month and then select the top three. This is the code I have so far. I thought that I could sort the data by using a variable and then calling for the sorted variable int the next line but that doesn't work. Instead I get a TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly. Any guidance is much appreciated. [image: This is the data I'm trying to sort]

Thank you.

```
import os
import csv
data = open('filteredData.csv','r')
# Create Dictionaries to store location values
# Snow_Fall is the number of inches for that location
# Number_Days is the number of days that there is Snowfall data for
Snow_Fall = {}
Number_Days = {}

# Create CSV reader
csv1 = csv.DictReader(data,delimiter=',')
# read each row of the CSV file and process it
for row in csv1:
    # Check the date column and see if it is in 2017
    if "2017" in row["DATE"]:
        # Split the date into Month, Day and Year
        Month, Day, Year = row["DATE"].split("/")
        # Check to see if the value in the snow column is null/none if so then skip processing that row
        if (row["SNOW"] is None) or (row["SNOW"] == ""):
            pass
        else:
            # Check to see if the location has been added to the dict if it has then add the data to itself
            # If it has not then just assign the data to the location.
            # Concat the Location and Month together to get a unique location per month
           # print (" The location is ==> " + row["NAME"] + " <<++>> The Month is " + str(Month))
            name_date = row["NAME"] + "_" + str(Month)
            if name_date in Snow_Fall:
                Snow_Fall[name_date] = Snow_Fall[name_date] + float(row["SNOW"])
                Number_Days[name_date] = Number_Days[name_date] + 1

            else:
                Snow_Fall[name_date] = float(row["SNOW"])
                Number_Days[name_date] = 1

# For each location we want to print the data for that location
for location in Snow_Fall:
   # split the location into Name and month
   location_name, location_date = location.split("_")
   #print ("The number of inches for location " + location_name + " in the Month of " + location_date + " is " + str(Snow_Fall[location]))            
   #print ("The number of days of snowfall for location " + " in the Month of " + location_date+ location_name + " is " + str(Number_Days[location]))
   #print ("The average Number of Inches for location " + location_name + " in the Month of " + location_date + " is " + str(Snow_Fall[location] / Number_Days[location]))

# Check if file exists then remove it if it does   
if (os.path.isfile('average2017.csv')):
   os.remove('average2017.csv')
# Open file   
data2 = open('average2017.csv','w')
# Write File headers
data2.write("Location, Month, Average Snow Fall \n")
# Write contents of the file
for location in Snow_Fall:
    # SPlit the location into name and month
    location_name, location_date = location.split("_")
    average = str(Snow_Fall[location] / Number_Days[location])
    newaverage = sorted([average])
    data2.write('"' + location_name + '",' + location_date + "," + newaverage + "\n")
# Close the open files
data2.close()
data.close()
```

**Information below is from a test**

runfile('U:/CISP253/Final/temp.py', wdir='U:/CISP253/Final')
                                              Location   Month  \
0                                  SPARTA 2.8 W, MI US       8
1                                  SPARTA 2.8 W, MI US       9
2                                      ROCKFORD, MI US      12
3                                      ROCKFORD, MI US      11
4                              KENTWOOD 1.6 WSW, MI US       2
5                                  SPARTA 2.8 W, MI US       5
6                                  SPARTA 2.8 W, MI US       6
7                                  SPARTA 2.8 W, MI US       7
8                              KENTWOOD 1.6 WSW, MI US       5
9                         COMSTOCK PARK 3.7 NNE, MI US      12
10                            CALEDONIA 4.4 WNW, MI US       9
11                        COMSTOCK PARK 3.7 NNE, MI US      10
12                         GRAND RAPIDS 4.6 ESE, MI US      12
13                             ROCKFORD 0.9 NNE, MI US       5
14                         GRAND RAPIDS 4.6 ESE, MI US      10
15                         GRAND RAPIDS 4.6 ESE, MI US      11
16                            CALEDONIA 4.4 WNW, MI US       3
17                            CALEDONIA 4.4 WNW, MI US       2
18                            CALEDONIA 4.4 WNW, MI US       1
19                            CALEDONIA 4.4 WNW, MI US       7
20                            CALEDONIA 4.4 WNW, MI US       6
21                            CALEDONIA 4.4 WNW, MI US       5
22                            CALEDONIA 4.4 WNW, MI US       4
23                             ROCKFORD 5.0 ESE, MI US       8
24                                     ROCKFORD, MI US       7
25                                     ROCKFORD, MI US       4
26                                     ROCKFORD, MI US       5
27                                     ROCKFORD, MI US       2
28                                     ROCKFORD, MI US       3
29                          GRAND RAPIDS 2.9 NW, MI US       4
..                                                 ...     ...
215                           ALLENDALE 1.3 SSW, MI US      11
216                             BELMONT 1.0 WNW, MI US       2
217                             BELMONT 1.0 WNW, MI US       5
218                             BELMONT 1.0 WNW, MI US       4
219                             BELMONT 1.0 WNW, MI US       7
220                             BELMONT 1.0 WNW, MI US       6
221                             BELMONT 1.0 WNW, MI US       9
222                             BELMONT 1.0 WNW, MI US       8
223                        GRAND RAPIDS 2.5 ENE, MI US       7
224                              JENISON 1.0 NE, MI US      10
225                              JENISON 1.0 NE, MI US      11
226  GRAND RAPIDS GERALD R FORD INTERNATIONAL AIRPO...      12
227                         GRAND RAPIDS 2.9 NW, MI US       9
228  GRAND RAPIDS GERALD R FORD INTERNATIONAL AIRPO...      10
229  GRAND RAPIDS GERALD R FORD INTERNATIONAL AIRPO...      11
230                           EAST GRAND RAPIDS, MI US      12
231                           EAST GRAND RAPIDS, MI US      11
232                           EAST GRAND RAPIDS, MI US      10
233                       COMSTOCK PARK 3.7 NNE, MI US       8
234                            KENTWOOD 1.6 WSW, MI US       7
235                        GRAND RAPIDS 2.5 ENE, MI US      11
236                              JENISON 1.0 NE, MI US       8
237                              JENISON 1.0 NE, MI US       9
238                              JENISON 1.0 NE, MI US       6
239                              JENISON 1.0 NE, MI US       7
240                              JENISON 1.0 NE, MI US       4
241                              JENISON 1.0 NE, MI US       5
242                       COMSTOCK PARK 3.7 NNE, MI US      11
243                       COMSTOCK PARK 1.0 NNW, MI US       7
244                                   ADA 1.8 W, MI US       1

```
  AverageSnowFall
```

0             0.000000
1             0.000000
2             0.948387
3             0.400000
4             0.000000
5             0.000000
6             0.000000
7             0.000000
8             0.000000
9             1.150000
10            0.000000
11            0.000000
12            2.390000
13            0.000000
14            0.000000
15            0.025000
16            0.408696
17            0.816667
18            0.647826
19            0.000000
20            0.000000
21            0.000000
22            0.415000
23            0.000000
24            0.000000
25            0.900000
26            0.000000
27            1.020000
28            0.928571
29            0.362500
..                 ...
215           0.050000
216           0.172727
217           0.025000
218           0.000000
219           0.000000
220           0.000000
221           0.000000
222           0.000000
223           0.000000
224           0.000000
225           0.000000
226           1.193548
227           0.000000
228           0.000000
229           0.026667
230           1.264516
231           0.033333
232           0.000000
233           0.000000
234           0.000000
235           1.000000
236           0.000000
237           0.000000
238           0.000000
239           0.000000
240           0.000000
241           0.000000
242           0.000000
243           0.000000
244           0.609677

[245 rows x 3 columns]
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('U:/CISP253/Final/temp.py', wdir='U:/CISP253/Final')

File "C:\Users\dwillaford\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\dwillaford\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "U:/CISP253/Final/temp.py", line 5, in 
    data = data.sort_values(by=['AverageSnowFall'])

File "C:\Users\dwillaford\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3619, in sort_values
    k = self.xs(by, axis=other_axis).values

File "C:\Users\dwillaford\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2335, in xs
    return self[key]

File "C:\Users\dwillaford\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2139, in **getitem**
    return self._getitem_column(key)

File "C:\Users\dwillaford\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2146, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)

File "C:\Users\dwillaford\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1842, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)

File "C:\Users\dwillaford\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3843, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)

File "C:\Users\dwillaford\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2527, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'AverageSnowFall'

Comment: For working with tables and dataframes like these, it's highly recommended to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to use pandas? So that way I don't have to rewrite everything?

Comment: Probably, but pandas will only take around 5 lines.

Comment: Also: Are you looking to find the 3 locations with the most snowfall for each month? Or just 3 locations which had the most snowfall in any month?

Comment: 3 highest for any month I assume i can read top 3 rows once I sort biggest to smallest

Comment: You should say if this is a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

This example is tailor-made for using a [Pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html). You can read in your csv to a dataframe, sort by values of different columns, get subsets of your dataframe, etc. This is how I would do it for your example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('filteredData.csv')
# Sort dataframe by Average Snow Fall column
data = data.sort_values(by=['Average Snow Fall'])
# Get the top 3 locations by average snow fall
print data['Location'].iloc[:3]
```

Comment: I'm getting a key error for 'Average Snow Fall' and I followed how you set yours up. The only thing I did differently is I used                                     
 data = pd.read_csv('average2016.csv'). I did create a new file instead of adding that on to the one I already had.

Comment: Try printing the data frame after read_csv - likely it's some problem with reading in the headers correctly. Actually after looking at it I bet it's creating three columns, one with name 'Average', another 'Snow', another 'Fall'. Take out the spaces and try it again

Comment: So then how do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Take the spaces out of your headers

Comment: Nope that still creates a key error... Sorry for so many questions I'm brand new to python.

Comment: After doing read_csv print the dataframe and post the output here - it's hard to say without seeing it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165674/discussion-between-raw-dawg-and-dominik).